# BeautifulSoup Python not able to scrape data from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to load the table data into csv from
a website
I ran the code below using Python and BeautifulSoup and could not load the data from it.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = 'https://newweb.nepalstock.com/floor-sheet'
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=agent)
print(BS(page.content, 'lxml'))

[Website image]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glflp.png
```

Comment: Are you sure about your url? I can't seem to access the website, even using a browser.

Comment: yes, its the same url. Maybe restriction of region? Nepal.
Please look into it.
:)

Comment: Seems to be a restriction of region indeed, could get it with a VPN. Your code isn't working because the website is returning javascript used to generate the tables instead of the html data itself. requests isn't adapted for those cases, I'd recommend you either try and find another website giving the same data, or look into [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example how to load the data into panda dataframes:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://newweb.nepalstock.com/api/nots/nepse-data/floorsheet"
params = {"page": "0", "size": "10", "sort": "contractId,desc"}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}

payload = {"id": 323}

for page in range(0, 4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    params["page"] = page

    data = requests.post(
        url, params=params, json=payload, headers=headers
    ).json()
    df = pd.json_normalize(data["floorsheets"]["content"])
    print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     id        contractId contractType stockSymbol buyerMemberId sellerMemberId  contractQuantity  contractRate  contractAmount businessDate  tradeBookId  stockId                          buyerBrokerName                       sellerBrokerName                   tradeTime                      securityName
0  None  2021060604039986         None         SGI            37             40               100         789.0         78900.0   2021-06-06     31492010     2908        Swarna Laxmi Securities Pvt. Ltd.            Creative Securities Pvt Ltd   2021-06-06T14:59:59.86245  Sanima General Insurance Limited
1  None  2021060604039985         None         EIC            37             52               115         758.0         87170.0   2021-06-06     31492008      181        Swarna Laxmi Securities Pvt. Ltd.            Sundhara Securities Limited  2021-06-06T14:59:59.862008        Everest Insurance Co. Ltd.
2  None  2021060604039984         None        UPCL             4             37               500         278.0        139000.0   2021-06-06     31492006     2810    Opal Securities Investment (PVT) Ltd.      Swarna Laxmi Securities Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.861311       UNIVERSAL POWER COMPANY LTD
3  None  2021060604039983         None        UPCL            43             37               200         278.0         55600.0   2021-06-06     31492001     2810              South Asian Bulls Pvt. Ltd.      Swarna Laxmi Securities Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.861051       UNIVERSAL POWER COMPANY LTD
4  None  2021060604039982         None        UPCL            52             37               100         278.0         27800.0   2021-06-06     31491998     2810              Sundhara Securities Limited      Swarna Laxmi Securities Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.860753       UNIVERSAL POWER COMPANY LTD
5  None  2021060604039981         None        UPCL            26             37               164         278.0         45592.0   2021-06-06     31491994     2810            Asian Securities Private Ltd.      Swarna Laxmi Securities Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.860336       UNIVERSAL POWER COMPANY LTD
6  None  2021060601066427         None         KBL            36             49                35         375.0         13125.0   2021-06-06     31491990      142                  Secured Securities Ltd.            Online Securities Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.813562               Kumari Bank Limited
7  None  2021060601066426         None         KBL            36             17                65         375.0         24375.0   2021-06-06     31491983      142                  Secured Securities Ltd.         ABC Securities Private Limited  2021-06-06T14:59:59.810103               Kumari Bank Limited
8  None  2021060604039980         None         LEC             5             53               140         355.0         49700.0   2021-06-06     31491979     2903  Market Securities & Exchange (PVT) Ltd.  Investment Management Nepal Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.793939    Liberty Energy Company Limited
9  None  2021060604039979         None         LEC            45             53               860         355.0        305300.0   2021-06-06     31491978     2903    Imperial Securities Company Pvt. Ltd.  Investment Management Nepal Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.793507    Liberty Energy Company Limited
     id        contractId contractType stockSymbol buyerMemberId sellerMemberId  contractQuantity  contractRate  contractAmount businessDate  tradeBookId  stockId                            buyerBrokerName                                   sellerBrokerName                   tradeTime                                  securityName
0  None  2021060604039978         None         NLG            38              4               500        1289.0        644500.0   2021-06-06     31491972      559  Dipshikha Dhitopatra Karobar Co. Pvt Ltd.              Opal Securities Investment (PVT) Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.270336                    NLG Insurance Company Ltd.
1  None  2021060604039977         None         HGI             4             53                10         802.0          8020.0   2021-06-06     31491969      179      Opal Securities Investment (PVT) Ltd.              Investment Management Nepal Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.266544           Himalayan General Insurance Co. Ltd
2  None  2021060604039976         None         HGI             4             58                50         802.0         40100.0   2021-06-06     31491964      179      Opal Securities Investment (PVT) Ltd.                          Naasa Securities Co. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.266101           Himalayan General Insurance Co. Ltd
3  None  2021060603064119         None       GMFIL            38             19                59         412.0         24308.0   2021-06-06     31491961      263  Dipshikha Dhitopatra Karobar Co. Pvt Ltd.  Nepal Investment And Securities Trading Privat...  2021-06-06T14:59:59.052083  Guheshowori Merchant Bank & Finance Co. Ltd.
4  None  2021060603064118         None       GMFIL            38              4               250         412.0        103000.0   2021-06-06     31491956      263  Dipshikha Dhitopatra Karobar Co. Pvt Ltd.              Opal Securities Investment (PVT) Ltd.   2021-06-06T14:59:59.05199  Guheshowori Merchant Bank & Finance Co. Ltd.
5  None  2021060603064117         None       GMFIL            38             45               150         412.0         61800.0   2021-06-06     31491951      263  Dipshikha Dhitopatra Karobar Co. Pvt Ltd.              Imperial Securities Company Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.051891  Guheshowori Merchant Bank & Finance Co. Ltd.
6  None  2021060603064116         None       GMFIL            38             38               411         411.0        168921.0   2021-06-06     31491947      263  Dipshikha Dhitopatra Karobar Co. Pvt Ltd.          Dipshikha Dhitopatra Karobar Co. Pvt Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.051779  Guheshowori Merchant Bank & Finance Co. Ltd.
7  None  2021060603064115         None       GMFIL            38             45                78         411.0         32058.0   2021-06-06     31491943      263  Dipshikha Dhitopatra Karobar Co. Pvt Ltd.              Imperial Securities Company Pvt. Ltd.  2021-06-06T14:59:59.051665  Guheshowori Merchant Bank & Finance Co. Ltd.

...and so on.
```